# jmoiron/sqlx, ...interface{}, and abstracting some boilerplate

Tags: go, sqlx

I thought I'd try to be a little bit "clever" and abstract some of my boilerplate SQL code (using sqlx -- https://github.com/jmoiron/sqlx). The idea is to feed a code a function pointer to process the result, along with the sql string and args that produce the rows. As it happens, the code works fine provided I strip out the "sqlArgs interface" stuff, but in the "cleverer" format errors with the statement

sql: converting Exec argument $1 type: unsupported type []interface {}, a slice of interface

Here are two versions, the first one that errors, the second that works but without parameterization:

```
//GetRows (doesn't work)
func GetRows(parseRows func(*sqlx.Rows), sql string, sqlArgs ...interface{}) {
    db := sqlx.MustConnect("mysql", ConnString)

    defer db.Close()

    rows, err := db.Queryx(sql, sqlArgs)

    defer rows.Close()

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    parseRows(rows)

}

//GetRows ... (works, but doesn't allow parameterization)
func GetRows(fp func(*sqlx.Rows), sql string) {

    db := sqlx.MustConnect("mysql", ConnString)

    defer db.Close()

    rows, err := db.Queryx(sql)

    defer rows.Close()

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fp(rows)

}
```

The idea is to call the code something like this:

```
func getUser(userID string) User {

    var users []*User

    parseRows := func(rows *sqlx.Rows) {
        for rows.Next() {
            var u User
            err := rows.StructScan(&u)

            if err != nil {
                panic(err)
            }

            users = append(users, u)
        }
    }

    sql := "SELECT * FROM users WHERE userid = ?;"

    sqlutils.GetRows(parseRows, sql, userID)

    if len(users) == 1{
        return users[0]
    }

    return User{}

}
```

I guess my code doesn't actually pass through the userID from call to call, but instead it passes an []interface{}, which the sql package can't handle. I'm not sure about that, however. In any case, is there any way to accomplish this idea? Thanks.

Comment: Include the code that doesn't work. I suspect you're passing `args`, not `args...`

Comment: So the func getUser() code above doesn't work, in particular, the line sqlutils.GetRows(parseRows, sql, userID) will fail. I'm not sure whether userID is an args or args...

Comment: Ah, in fact your intuition is correct. I hunted down a call in which I passed exactly that, args and not args... It's fixed now (I think ... still more checking to do).